# Filtering 'timestamp' data from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using **AngularFire2** and trying to query a certain range of data based on `TimeStamp`.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
this.db.list('timeRecords/' + this.userID + '/' + this.teamRef, ref
         => ref.orderByChild('timeStamp')
    .startAt("<starting_timestamp>")
    .endAt("<ending_timestamp>"))
    .valueChanges().subscribe(data => {

     console.log(data)
})
```

The `data` returns an empty array !!

The data at the Firebase DB (on the specified node i:e `'timeRecords/' + this.userID + '/' + this.teamRef` ) is shown in the `public gist` at the following URL:

https://gist.github.com/DevlprArup/3fe83e6e6082d5b1d419bc8a1831cef4

How do I get an Array containing the specified range ??

Comment: all in all it looks quite okay to me. Only thing i can see is that you put in "..." timestamp as starting / ending timestamp. Please make sure it is a number!

Comment: @djnose .. but it still returns an empty array !!!

Comment: after checking your link with the data it kinda looks like you are querying the wrong way. could you try this: `this.db.list('timeRecords/' + this.teamRef + '/' + this.userID` ?